# Spring jdbc vs iBatis

Tags: ibatis, spring-jdbc

For Spring 2.5.6 and above the two reasons that I can think of for choosing spring jdbc are :

1. BeanPropertySqlParameterSource - for
   insert/update
2. ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper -
   for select

These two give you the power of basic orm as you don't need to code your rowmappers.

Thoughts/Comments?

Answer (score 4):

IBatis gives you [caching](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s08.html) out of the box which SpringJDBC doesn't. Some people might rather prefer using a declarative approach (in IBatis it's XML) to define their queries. Using left joins to [populate 1:n relationships without running n+1 selects](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s05.html) might be easier to do with IBatis. In the end you can use both approaches in the same project and cherry-pick the framework of your choice based on the problem you want to solve.